# I can't use Speech recognition in python

Tags: error-handling, speech-recognition, python-3.8

the speech recognition is not working 
here is my code :

```
import speech_recognition

robot_ear = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
with speech_recognition.Microphone() as mic:
    print ("Robot: I'm listening")
    audio = robot_ear.listen(mic)

you = robot_ear.recognize_google(audio)

print(you)
```

but the computer does not response to what I spoke

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "nghe1.py", line 6, in
> <module>
>     audio = robot_ear.listen(mic)   File "C:\Users\Jean\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py",
> line 652, in listen
>     buffer = source.stream.read(source.CHUNK)   File "C:\Users\Jean\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py",
> line 161, in read
>     return self.pyaudio_stream.read(size, exception_on_overflow=False)   File
> "C:\Users\Jean\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyaudio.py",
> line 608, in read
>     return pa.read_stream(self._stream, num_frames, exception_on_overflow)
```

please show me how can I fix this

Answer (score 0):

I have done speech recognition in python the code is very simple:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

rObject = sr.Recognizer() 
audio = '' 
with sr.Microphone() as source: 
    print("Speak...")   
    audio = rObject.listen(source, phrase_time_limit = 0) 
    print("Stop.")
    try: 
        text = rObject.recognize_google(audio, language ='en-US') 
        print("You : "+ text)  
    except: 
        speak("Could not understand your audio...PLease try again !")
```

Try it , hope it will work according to your desired output .